# Store user certificate into WSO2 IS account

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

is there a way to store user certificates into WSO2 Identity Server account space? I mean, make WSO2IS work as SoftHSM? This requirement is necessary because there are some external services that needs user certificate to authenticate user before any call.

So I was thinking about possibility to store it in user account, retrieve and send to request when need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably store that as a `String` user claim. But the ideal way would be to store the cert in their truststore rather than fetched from the Identity Server.

Comment: Yes but what if there is milions of users? I believe a truststore is not designed to store so many certs, am I right? I was thinking about a kind of HSM but something software based.